# How to SELECT records if the absolute value of the difference between two values if greater than a certain number?

Tags: mysql

I have two fields that are of type int `lap_time_1` and `lap_time_2` .  Is there a mysql query to select the records whose difference (absolute value) between lap 1 and lap 2 is greater than 30?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This assumes lap_time_1 and lap_time_2 are two columns and the data is held on the same row.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ABS(lap_time_1 - lap_time_2) > 30
```

Comment: i have both the column UNSIGNED so having this error  `BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(left_side - right_side)'`. any clue how to compare ? exe query `SELECT * FROM packages WHERE ABS(left_side - right_side) > 1000 LIMIT 1000`

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does have an absolute value (ABS) [mathematical function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs).  So you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM lap
WHERE ABS(lap_time_1 - lap_time_2) > 30;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTABLE
WHERE ABS(lap_time1 - lap_time2) > 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward. I did the same to calculate the relative distance of a point of sale to a customer.

```
select * from <table> where abs(field1 - field2) > 30
```